# Redirecting doesn't work with a custom form in a block

Tags: forms, blocks, uri, redirection

I developed a custom form with FAPI and added a block for it.

Block is included only on one specific page (basic node).

When user submits this form it should redirect user to external site (URL is a return value from another external site).
For this purpose I've used $form['redirect'] which was working when this form was used as standalone page.
In block it won't redirect and instead the same page is loaded.

I tried other methods too for redirecting such as php header location and drupal_goto but none of them work.

Perhaps there is something node level overriding that prevents the form redirect?

EDIT:

Block is a very basic implementation on code level. API based hook_info and hook_view functions accompanied with custom content function (which returns form markup:**drupal_get_form('my_form')**).

**The redirect** is defined on **hook_form_submit($form, &$form_state)** in which it first makes two calls to external web services and based on return values it either redirects or shows message:

```
// Debug shows that this evaluates true          
if (!filter_var($webservice1, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) {
    $form_state['redirect'] = $webservice1;
} else if ($webservice1 == 'ok' && $webservice2 == 'ok') {
    drupal_set_message(theme_item_list($formvalues),'status');
} else {
  drupal_set_message('Error', 'error');
}
```

Comment: please show your code, without it we can only guess at what is wrong

Comment: does the form submit, and does the page refresh? I ask because it could be assuming as a block form, it's an ajax call and thus bypassing any redirect

Comment: Yes, it does submit and also the page is refreshed. Referring to above piece of code I tried also drupal_set_message in place of redirect it showed status message, so it confirms that.

Comment: are you sure $webservice1 is still returning the correct value - I don't know why it would change from a page to a block, but weird things do happen

Comment: If it wasn't it wouldn't evaluate true in 1st if statement. Perhaps I need to create a temporary workaround and just print that webservice URL as link in status message. Or even in a modal/popup. But the best case would automatic redirect without extra steps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the redirect should be `$form_state['redirect']`

Comment: Yes it is. Like stated in the description it works that way if the form is used as standalone page. Now that it is as block content the same method doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: in your answer you wrote `$form['redirect']` instead of `$form_state['redirect']`